# Add class to every 3rd element and exclude elements with X class

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to write a function that loops through all my elements and adds a class to every 3rd element (1, 4, 7, 10 etc) UNLESS that element has the class 'foo'...

Is their a way to do this within my loop?

```
$('.container12 > .grid_12 > .grid_4').filter(function (index) { 
   return index % 3 === 0;
}).addClass("alpha");
```

Comment: To exclude a class you can do something like `.addClass('alpha').not('.x');`

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck you'd probably want to filter _before_ adding the class, no?

Comment: Yes, I was just giving a simple example of how it could be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

how about this:

```
$('.container12 > .grid_12 > .grid_4').filter(function (index) { 
   return !$(this).hasClass('x') && index % 3 === 0;
}).addClass("alpha");
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Gbz7C/7/)

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [nth-child](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) selector :

```
$('.container12 > .grid_12 > .grid_4:nth-child(3n+1):not(\'.foo\')')
.addClass("alpha");
```

[**See fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4ntfs/1)

Comment: This is the best approach, IMO—the `nth-child` selector is far more succinct than `filter`.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for the `:not()` selector:

Try this:

```
$(".container12 > .grid_12 > .grid_4 li:not('.foo')")
    .filter(function (index) { 
       return index % 3 === 0;
    })
    .addClass("alpha");
```

It applies the `alpha` class to every 3rd element, ignoring the elements with the class `foo`.

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MatthewKeefe/nCdwG/)**